# Getting Error in TableAdapter Query Wizard when adding parameterized queries

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Here is my query

```
SELECT        ID, ccnumberexp, EntireName, address, stateinit, zip, age, email, ccnumber, SignupDate, MemberTypes
FROM            MemberBase
WHERE        (SignupDate BETWEEN [@date1] AND [@date2])
```

and when I run it in query builder I get

Excecuted SQL Statement:...
Error Source: Microsoft Access Database Engine
Error Message: No value given for one or more parameters

I thought that it was supposed to ask you to supply given parameters?

---

Also when this is done how do I supply parameters in vb.net?

Comment: Can you show how you’re executing this query?

Comment: @Hursey sorry I do not understand what you are asking

Comment: The problem isn’t you’re query,  it’s how you’re executing it.  Can you show the vb.net code where creating your connection and executing the query?

Comment: @Hursey oh no not really. I am using the tableadapter query wizard. if I leave the WHERE as SignupDate Between ? and ? It will work fine via a subprocedure. I'm really trying to get it to work but I can't find anything online and I spent my entire day trying to get this to work.

Comment: Then leave it with the question marks.  The Query Builder requires that in many cases where you would use a named parameter in your own inline SQL.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I believe this is the correct answer.